# How can I use a custom error handler in a Yesod route handler?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, yesod

I have a project that has two parts:

- Webpage
- API

I'm using the `errorHandler` function in my `Yesod` instance declaration to build error pages for the webpage when something goes wrong.

However all routes in the API creates `JSON` responses. I'm using `runInputPost` to generate a input form that handles input to the API. When the API is called with missing parameters Yesod generates the `InvalidArgs` exception and the error HTML-page is returned.

I want to be able to handle that exception and return `JSON` such as:

```
{
  "success" : False,
  "code"    : 101,
  "message" : "The argument 'blabla' was missing"
}
```

**How can I do that without creating a subsite with it's own `errorHandler`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your solution certainly works, you could instead use the [runInputPostResult](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/yesod-form/Yesod-Form-Input.html#v:runInputPostResult) function, which was actually added via PR by someone in pretty much the same situation you find yourself in.

Comment: Cool! Will look into that next time I bump the yesod version in my project. Thank you!

Comment: For the record, that function's been around for a while.

Comment: Even better :) I'm accepting this answer since it's a solution that already exists in Yesod.

Answer (score 1):

After reading about how to catch exceptions that happens in monad stacks ([here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/general-haskell/exceptions/exceptions-and-monad-transformers) and [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/06/exceptions-transformers)) I found out about the library [`exceptions`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) which seemed easy to use.

I read about which type in `Yesod` that implements the `Exception` type class, turns out it's a type called [`HandlerContents`](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/972e117005b08172a330b78b669814b43ab64b5f/yesod-core/Yesod/Core/Types.hs#L358):

```
data HandlerContents =
      HCContent H.Status !TypedContent
    | HCError ErrorResponse
    | HCSendFile ContentType FilePath (Maybe FilePart)
    | HCRedirect H.Status Text
    | HCCreated Text
    | HCWai W.Response
    | HCWaiApp W.Application
    deriving Typeable
```

I'm interested in `HCError` since it contains `ErrorResponse` (same type that `errorHandler` gets).

I added the `exceptions` library to `build-depends` in my cabal-file. All my handlers in the API had the signature `:: Handler Value` so I created a utility function called `catchRouteError` that I could run my handlers with:

```
catchRouteError :: Handler Value -> Handler Value
catchRouteError r = catch r handleError
  where
    handleError :: HandlerContents -> Handler Value
    handleError (HCError (InvalidArgs _)) = ... create specific json error
    handleError (HCError _)               = ... create generic json error
    handleError e                         = throwM e
```

Since `HandlerContents` is used for other things such as redirection and receiving files I only match against `HCError` and let the default implementation handle everything else.

Now I could easily run my handlers with this function:

```
postAPIAppStatusR :: Handler Value
postAPIAppStatusR = catchRouteError $ do
    ...
```

That's a quick solution to my problem, I'm sure there are more elegant solutions that people with better `Yesod` knowledge can provide.

Comment: to fill in the ... - you probably want something like this:

      sendResponseStatus status400 (object [ "error_invalid" .= show a ])

if you just return an Aeson Value, you'll get a 200 response, which isn't really right.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Mark!